# How can i limit the wrong password attempts in Firebase email login?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have to limit the wrong password attempts in Firebase Email login system. I am using the basic firebase code for login and sign up.

```
private List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers;
providers= Arrays.asList(
    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build());
    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
            .build(),
            RC_EMAIL_SIGN_IN);

    if (requestCode == RC_EMAIL_SIGN_IN)
    {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Successfully signed in
            FirebaseUser user = 
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        } else {
            Log.d("Email Sign up" ,  "Fail");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The open source library you're using, [Firebase-UI for Authentication](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md), is handling the sign in flow for you.  If you want to change its behavior, you'll have to modify it yourself, build a new version, and use that in your app.  It doesn't have a configuration to limit the number of failed attempts.

Comment: Ok Thank for your reply